# vim: Using <afile> in an autogroup command

Tags: vim, erb

My goal is to highlight `<basename>.<extension>.erb` files as I would highlight `<basename>.<extension>` files.

As a first pass, I'm fine with supporting `<basename>.<filetype>.erb`, which I tried to do with

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.erb setf <afile>:r:e
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.  What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the special character expansion is only done when typing command.
However you can call the `expand` function.

```
 au BufNewFile,BufRead *.erb setf=expand("<afile>:r:e")
```

Should answer your question  (but It doesn't seem to work for what you want to do).

Comment: I'm on my phone now, but maybe set ft=expand('<afile>:r:e') will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.*.erb execute 'doautocmd BufRead ' . expand(':r')